# Mariadb configuration Optimization

Tags: mysql, sql, database, configuration, mariadb

I've a server ( 2x Xeon E5620 / 32 GB DDR3 ECC REG RAM / 250 GB SSD / 1 IPv4) which hosts a site with an important trafic (1000 users connected at the same time approximately) , Mysql queries are very slow when the site reaches the 1500 users connected at the same time .

I'am using Mariadb & Innodb , and all my tables have the good indexes .
I think th problem is that i did'nt change the default mysql.cnf file .

How i can optimize it for make MySql running fast as possible ??

PS : Sorry for my bad english

Comment: What should I do is to, run the `mysql tuner`(https://github.com/major/MySQLTuner-perl), check the recommendations and then the `Percona Configuration Wizard for MySQL` from https://tools.percona.com ..this should generates a mysql.cnf optimized for your hardware and system specs :)

Comment: "all my tables have the good indexes" -- Prove it.  Let's see some of the more common queries, especially against larger tables.  And provide `EXPLAIN SELECT...` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: "You can't tune your way out of performance problems".  However, sometimes the tunables give good clues.  Please provide `SHOW VARIABLES;` and `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;` -- I'll check the most important setting (`innodb_buffer_pool_size`) plus about 200 less critical things.

Comment: For example, if there are really 1000 _active_ connections at once, `table_open_cache` may be too small; there are status values that would say whether it is too small.

Comment: Another example:  lots of created tmp tables on disk indicates index and/or schema and/or query issues, hence my request to see all of those.